# Best way to remove kwargs from SQLAlchemy query's `filter_by` option if they are not provided

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to remove key pair values if they are not provided in my payload from SQLAlchemy query.

```py
payload1 = {
    "username": "James",
    "ssn": "102-00-1911",
    "state": "New York"
}

payload2 = {
    "username": "James"
}


def search_database(body):
    """
        Searches Database for user
    """
    query = db_session.query(DatabaseModel).filter_by(
        username=body['username'],
        ssn=body.get('ssn', None), # kwarg should be omitted if it's not in body
        state=body.get('state', None), # kwarg should be omitted if it's not in body
    ).all()

    return query


search_database(payload1) # should not omit anything
search_database(payload2) # Should omit `ssn` and `state` from query
```

Currently I'm unable to find a way to dynamically remove a key pair from my query. I tried passing `None` as an alternative to the value if a key is missing but that did not work.

If the payload is missing `ssn` or `state` I would like to omit it from the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized you can pass a dictionary in `filter_by`. I was able to filter using a Dict comprehension on the `body` before passing it to the query.

```py
def search_database(body):
    """
        Searches Database for user
    """

    permitted = [
        "username",
        "ssn",
        "state"
    ]

    filtered = {key: body[key] for key in permitted if key in body}
    query = db_session.query(DatabaseModel).filter_by(**filtered).all()

    return query
```